# Initial mono for android installation quits after first screen with no error message

Tags: xamarin.android, failed-installation, installation-package

I downloaded the trial version for Mono for android and tried to install on Windows 7.  After the first confirmation page the installer quits with no error message.

I've searched for the net and found nothing. I tried to unblock the file and move it to the desktop and click the box to run with administrator priviledges.  I've also tried to download and run and dowload and save.

I'm in China, don't know if the great firewall could effect this???

With no error message I'm lost on how to proceed.

Comment: Are you sure you're trying to install MonoTouch on Windows? Just to make sure we're all talking about the same thing, MonoTouch is the run-your-C# on iOS development tool from Xamarin. It requires MacOS to do much of anything. (Mostly, but not absolutely, Apple's fault.) Another possibility is that you mean just Mono or perhaps Mono for Android.

Comment: Ah! that would be Mono for Android then.

Comment: Tried this on another computer also running windows 7 and using hotspot vpn.  Same issue.

Comment: Going for silverlight and XNA on the windows phone instead.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes this can be caused by network connectivity issues or proxies. You can try to install the components manually:

1. JDK 1.6: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk-6u31-download-1501634.html
   Please choose the jdk-6u31-windows-i586.exe installer from the list above.
2. Android SDK: http://dl.google.com/android/installer_r21-windows.exe
   After the main installer is done, please open the SDK Manager and install the following platform APIs: 7,8,10,12,14
3. GTK#: http://download.xamarin.com/Installer/gtk-sharp-2.12.10.win32.msi
4. MonoDevelop: http://download.xamarin.com/monodevelop/Windows/MonoDevelop-3.0.5.msi
5. Mono for Android SDK: http://download.xamarin.com/MonoforAndroid/Windows/mono-android-4.2.7.15330979.msi

You can skip steps 3 and 4 if you don't need/want to use MonoDevelop and use VisualStudio (2010 Professional or better) instead. In that case you must have VS installed before proceeding with step 5.